# Read json file & print only specific rows

Tags: node.js, json

I have below json data file & want to do below things:

1. Read json file & check row count (this is completed)
2. I have setup maxRowCnt=2 so I need to print only 2 rows from json file

Sample Json File:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "User1",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "user2",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "user3",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "user4",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "user5",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "user6",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "user7",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  }
]
```

#2 I tried to print json data but getting data as follows:

```
Json Data---"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

Code:

```
const fs = require("fs");

let jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./test/sampleData1.json', 'utf8'));

console.log('Debug1---'+typeof(jsonData));

let jsonRowCount = jsonData.length;
let maxRowCount = 2;

console.log("JSON ROW COUNT Printed here---"+jsonRowCount);

let jsonData1 = jsonData.toString().split('\n');

console.log('Debug2---'+typeof(jsonData1));

for(let i=1; i <= maxRowCount; i++){
  
  console.log("i Value Print---"+i);

  console.log("Json Data---"+JSON.stringify(jsonData1);
  
}
```

Output Should be:

```
  [{
    "Name": "User1",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  },
  {
    "Name": "user2",
    "primaryRegion": "US"
  }]
```

Comment: you already have parsed JSON data so you can do `jsonData.splice(0, maxRowCount)` to get the needed rows and then you can `stringify` them back if needed